# How to write scripts to test an application using Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I want to do load testing of an application. How to write scripts for doing load testing (signup, search etc).

Comment: This is far too broad to answer. Please read [ask] and the [help] when you get a moment. This question seems to have escaped closure so far, it should have been closed in 2014.

Answer (score 0):

do a google search for "learn JMeter in 60 minutes":
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cv7KqxaLZd8